# angular: make angular material buttons act like radio buttons

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I'm losing my mind figuring out how to create buttons that act like radio buttons. I mean that I can click them and they stay pressed, and I can get the values from the controller

```
     <div layout="row" layout-align="center">
       <md-button class="btn" ng-click="vm.modifyPackage(timPackage,timPackage.minutes,false)"> - </md-button>
         <span class="md-subhead">{{ timPackage.minutes }} Minutes </span>
       <md-button class="btn" ng-click="vm.modifyPackage(timPackage,timPackage.minutes,true)"> + </md-button>
     </div>
     <div layout="row" layout-align="center">
       <md-button class="btn" ng-click="vm.modifyPackage(timPackage,timPackage.sms,false)"> - </md-button>
         <span class="md-subhead">{{ timPackage.sms }} SMS </span>
       <md-button class="btn" ng-click="vm.modifyPackage(timPackage,timPackage.sms,true)"> + </md-button>
     </div>
     <div layout="row" layout-align="center">
       <md-button class="btn" ng-click="vm.modifyPackage(timPackage,timPackage.megabytes,false)"> - </md-button>
          <span class="md-subhead">{{ timPackage.megabytes }}GB Internet </span>
       <md-button class="btn" ng-click="vm.modifyPackage(timPackage,timPackage.megabytes,true)"> + </md-button>
     </div>
```

I know that I have to use the "activate" parameter somewhere, but I don't know where, and I have written a controller function yet because I don't know where to start.
Thanks to everyone who is gonna help me.

Comment: I can't remember, but I think there is something like "Toggle Buttons" available in Material... You should have a look at this. And, btw, pure css with a "pressed" class is not working? https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons.html#buttons-toggle-buttons

Comment: @Julo0sS there is, but i can't understand how it works. I tryied a lot of different code but nothing seems to work and im really gettin crazy about that

Comment: I have no time today, but I will have a closer look tomorrow afternoon if nobody else help you before

Comment: Why do you use the old "md-button", can't you update to material 2 and get the latest <mat-toggle-button-group> & <mat-toggle-button> directives? that's easy...